# What is the first recorded dog name?

Tags: names, animals

Dogs have an age-old relationship with humans, and nowadays almost all dogs have a name given to them.  In Homer's [Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey) (8th century BCE), upon Odysseus' return, his beloved dog Argos is the only one to recognize him.

Aptly named

> "man's best friend" is a common phrase about domestic dogs, referring
>   to their millennia-long history of close relations, loyalty, and
>   companionship with humans. The first recorded use of a related phrase
>   is by Frederick the Great of Prussia. <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27s_best_friend)</sub>

But which named dog is the oldest we know of in recorded history?

I have searched a lot of Wikipedia pages and internet articles, but I cannot seem to find any information.

Comment: A catalogue of dog names...?

Comment: Ah - Western bias ;) (j/k) I can't find the dates after a simple cursory search so I'm leaving a comment instead of an answer - but be sure to look into Chinese history. Panhu is one of the zodiac animals and was recognized by the She, a group with neolithic history

Answer (score 175, accepted):

A hunting dog ([tesem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesem)) named **Akbaru** is depicted in the tomb of the Fourth Dynasty pharaoh [Khufu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khufu#Length_of_reign) (died c. **2566 BC**).

There is a stone relief dated to circa **2400 BC** from the [Fifth Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Dynasty_of_Egypt) showing a dog called **Beha**, probably a greyhound. The name Beha is

> possibly an abbreviation of "behkai" (oryx antelope), a dog's name
>   known from other contexts

[image]

*Beha, Fifth Dynasty. Source: [Walters Art Museum [Public domain], via Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Egyptian_-_Man_with_Calf_and_Dog_-_Walters_22422_-_Detail_B.jpg)*

Beha was also the name of one of the dogs of the [Eleventh Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleventh_Dynasty_of_Egypt) pharaoh [Intef II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intef_II) (c. 2112–2063 BC); the dog's name was [carved on an individual stele](https://www.ancient.eu/article/1031/dogs-in-ancient-egypt/).

In the [Sixth Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Dynasty_of_Egypt) (c. **2345–2181 BC**), a guard dog named **Abuwtiyuw** was buried with his own [stele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stele), sometime [before 2280 BC](http://archaeologist-ticia-verveer.blogspot.com/2017/02/the-ancient-egyptian-royal-guard-dog.html) (unfortunately, it cannot be more precisely dated as the stele was reused in another construction so its original location is unknown). The (translated) inscription on it reads:

> The dog which was the guard of His Majesty. Abuwtiyuw is his name. His
>   Majesty ordered that he be buried (ceremonially), that he be given a
>   coffin from the royal treasury, fine linen in great quantity, (and)
>   incense. His Majesty (also) gave perfumed ointment, and (ordered) that
>   a tomb be built for him by the gangs of masons. His Majesty did this
>   for him in order that he (the dog) might be honored (before the great
>   god, Anubis).

*Source: George A. Reisner, '[The Dog Which Was Honored by the King of Upper and Lower Egypt](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4170605?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=The&searchText=Dog&searchText=Which&searchText=Was&searchText=Honored&searchText=by&searchText=the&searchText=King&searchText=of&searchText=Upper&searchText=and&searchText=Lower&searchText=Egypt&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3FQuery%3DThe%2BDog%2BWhich%2BWas%2BHonored%2Bby%2Bthe%2BKing%2Bof%2BUpper%2Band%2BLower%2BEgypt%26amp%3Bfilter%3D&ab_segments=0%2Fbasic_SYC-4929%2Ftest&refreqid=search%3A278bf4a262f40e028512b8bfecf9a33a&seq=1)'. In Bulletin of the Museum of Fine Arts Vol. 34, No. 206 (Dec., 1936)*

[image]

*Inscription of the Dog Abuwtiyuw. Source: [Archaeologist Ticia Verveer](http://archaeologist-ticia-verveer.blogspot.com/2017/02/the-ancient-egyptian-royal-guard-dog.html)*

As to the [meaning of the name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuwtiyuw),

> According to Reisner, the name "Abuwtiyuw" is not fully translatable,
>   but he surmised that ꜥbw ("abuw") is an onomatopoeic representation of
>   a dog's bark, as this component often is found in Ancient Egyptian dog
>   names.[26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yama_(Hinduism)) Edward C. Martin Jr. claims that the name means "With
>   Pointed Ears", which would fit the description of the Tesem.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khufu#Length_of_reign)

According to Reisner, Abuwtiyuw's breed was the "[greyhound or slugi (called *tsm* in Egyptian)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4170605?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=The&searchText=Dog&searchText=Which&searchText=Was&searchText=Honored&searchText=by&searchText=the&searchText=King&searchText=of&searchText=Upper&searchText=and&searchText=Lower&searchText=Egypt&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3FQuery%3DThe%2BDog%2BWhich%2BWas%2BHonored%2Bby%2Bthe%2BKing%2Bof%2BUpper%2Band%2BLower%2BEgypt%26amp%3Bfilter%3D&ab_segments=0%2Fbasic_SYC-4929%2Ftest&refreqid=search%3A278bf4a262f40e028512b8bfecf9a33a&seq=1)." [Other dog names](https://ancientegyptianfacts.com/ancient-egyptian-dogs.html) also survive from Ancient Egypt, though online sources do not give dates for the following:

> We even know many ancient Egyptian dog’s names from leather collars as
>   well as stelae and reliefs. They included names such as **Brave One,
>   Reliable, Good Herdsman, North-Wind, Antelope and even “Useless”**.
>   Other names come from the dogs color, such as Black, while still other
>   dogs were given numbers for names, such as “the Fifth”.

In Ancient Egypt, dogs commonly bore the [same names as humans](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1512730?seq=1), while some had [theophoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophoric_name) names (names which included the name of a god). Dogs,

> particularly the hunting dog or greyhound, played an intimate part in
>   the daily life of the kings and nobles of all periods in ancient
>   Egypt.

*Source: Reisner*

---

In Ancient Greece, dog naming was common. The Greek writer [Xenophon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenophon), in [Cynegeticus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynegeticus) ('On Hunting', **late 5th / early 4th century BC**) gives a list of [dog names](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0210:text=Hunt.:chapter=7) he thought suitable:

> Give the hounds short names, so as to be able to call to them easily.
>   The following are the right sort: Psyche, Thymus, Porpax, Styrax,
>   Lonchê, Lochus, Phrura, Phylax, Taxis, Xiphon, Phonax, Phlegon, Alcê,
>   Teuchon, Hyleus, Medas, Porthon, Sperchon, Orgê, Bremon, Hybris,
>   Thallon, Rhomê, Antheus, Hebe, Getheus, Chara, Leusson, Augo, Polys,
>   Bia, Stichon, Spudê, Bryas, Oenas, Sterrus, Craugê, Caenon, Tyrbas,
>   Sthenon, Aether, Actis, Aechmê, Noes, Gnomê, Stibon, Hormê.

The meanings of some of these names are explained in a footnote:

> The **names are significant of the colour, strength, spirit, sagacity or
>   behaviour of the hounds**. Hebe and Psyche are still in the list of
>   bitches' names, and modern equivalents of several of the other names
>   are in use, e.g., **Lance** (Lonchê), **Sentinel** (Phylax), **Ecstasy** (Chara),
>   **Blueskin** (Oenas), **Crafty** (Medas), **Hasty** (Sperchon), **Vigorous**
>   (Thallon), **Impetus** (Hormê), **Counsellor** (Noes), **Bustler** (dog) or **Hasty**
>   (bitch); cf. Sperchon. For Πολύς we should probably read Πολεύς,
>   “**Rover**.”

---

Given that dogs were [domesticated many thousands of years before even the Fourth Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog#Origin) in Egypt, it is quite likely that dogs were being given names before any of the ones mentioned above. However, there do not appear to be any older *known* names for non-mythical dogs than those from Ancient Egypt.

In mythology, *NKCampbell* mentioned Panhu in a comment; Panhu was supposedly the dog of the [Emperor Ku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Ku) (possibly reigned c. 2436 BC to c. 2366 BC though some classify Ku as semi-historical). In legend, [Panhu killed an enemy general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_in_Chinese_mythology#Panhu) and married Ku's daughter. Another mythical dog is [Sharvara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharvara) (meaning 'variegated or spotted') from Hinduism (mentioned in the [Vedas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas#Chronology)) and belonging to [Yama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yama_(Hinduism)), the lord of death and of justice. This mythical dog was one of two which "guarded the gates of the netherworld."

**(All emphasis is mine)**

Comment: This is an extraordinary answer! I wish i could upvote twice.

Comment: Let's not forget *Kerberos* (Spot)!

Comment: @Tom Your appreciation is worth at least a double upvote :) Save any bounty for a question that isn't getting enough attention, or for a good answer that hasn't had proper recognition (this question & answer is doing fine without a bounty).

Comment: “Useless” - huh. Never knew my dogs were Egyptian. :-)

Comment: It warms the cockles of my heart to learn that His Majesty named his dog (effectively) Woofers/Barky.

Answer (score 23):

Somebody has compiled info about Roman dogs, mostly literary  (Ovid) but also a few real ones, although sources for 'real' dogs may be questionable.

https://www.unrv.com/culture/names-for-roman-dogs.php

The oldest one appears to be this:
Perseus. m. The name of the dog of Aemilia Tertia, daughter of the **2nd century BC** Roman consul Lucius Aemilius Paullus Macedonicus.

Answer (score 20):

Long before well known [Cerberus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerberus) from Greek mythology the [Mesopotamian goddess](https://www.ancient.eu/article/1175/dogs--their-collars-in-ancient-mesopotamia/) [Bau, later named Gula](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Bau-Mesopotamian-deity), is depicted with a dog's head:

> Bau seems originally to have been goddess of the dog; as Nininsina she was long represented with a dog’s head, and the dog was her emblem.

[This dates from around 3300 B.C.](https://www.ancient.eu/article/1175/dogs--their-collars-in-ancient-mesopotamia/) when depictions of collared dogs appear in art.

[This page on ancient canine deities](https://www.dogster.com/lifestyle/dog-gods) claims:

> Scholars say Bau’s name is derived from the sound of barking, that it’s the first half of “bow wow.”

Comment: +1 for Cerberus, but the goddess Bau is certainly not a dog:-)

Comment: Bau? Wow! ......

Comment: @bmargulies: THWACK!!!! That is all, carry on.

Comment: @bmargulies: Edited - ***just*** for you.